# Spyderで間違えて閉じるボタンを押しても確認画面を出したい

Tags: python, spyder

Pythonの開発環境でSpyderを使っています。
回しているプログラムがシミュレーションを何度も使用するので(MCMCを用いたパラメータ推定です）一回回すと1~2日かかるのですが、
誤って閉じるボタンを押してしまうとプログラムが終了してしまい、時間の無駄になってしまいます。
閉じるボタンをクリックしてしまっても、警告ポップアップなどを表示して本当に閉じるのか確認できるようにしたいのですが、可能でしょうか。
可能であればそのやり方について教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メニューから

> ツール > 設定 > 一般 > 詳細設定
> 終了前に確認する

英語表記なら

> Tools > Preferences > General > Advanced Settings
> Prompt when exiting

IPythonコンソールについてのことなら, 同様に設定から

> IPythonコンソール
> 閉じる前に確認する